# Why is my mesh so much less smooth than the one in the tutorial I'm following?

Tags: mesh

I'm following a Blender tutorial and I've noticed that the mesh in the tutorial is significantly smoother than mine.

I was wondering if I just haven't moved things around and smoothed out my mesh manually enough (maybe I need more polygons?), or if the one in the tutorial is being displayed/shaded differently in the view.

Mine:
[image]

The tutorial's:
[image]

Credits: Tutorial is by Christian Bradley and is posted on Lynda.com

Comment: Two possibilities: or the tutorial uses 'smooth shading' and not your model (smooth shading can be set in the toolshelf in object mode in the shading section), or the tutorial uses a subdivision surface modifier.. or both of them

Comment: @Lemon Smooth shading was the answer! Thanks a lot for the simple solution, I appreciate it.